# Akka actor is returning type Any instead of Vector[Product]

Tags: scala, akka

I am calling this in akka:

```
for {
  products <- myActor ? MyActor.Search("...", 25)
} yield {
  val model = MyModel(products) 
}
```

The `MyModel(products)` line has an error saying expected `Vector[Product]`, actual `Any`.

the signature is this:

```
def search(searchText: String, hitsPerPage: Int): Vector[Product]
```

Why does it come back as type Any?

```
found   : Any
[error]  required: Vector[com.example.Product]
```

Do I need to cast the response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the official [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/futures.html#use-with-actors):

> Also note that the Future returned by an Actor is a `Future[Any]` since an Actor is dynamic....When using non-blocking it is better to use the `mapTo` method to safely try to cast a Future to an expected type:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import akka.pattern.ask

val future: Future[String] = ask(actor, msg).mapTo[String]
```

> The `mapTo` method will return a new `Future` that contains the result if the cast was successful, or a `ClassCastException` if not.

So you can use [`mapTo`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#mapTo[S](implicittag:scala.reflect.ClassTag[S]):scala.concurrent.Future[S]) to get a result of type `Vector[Product]`:

```
for {
  products <- (myActor ? MyActor.Search("...", 25)).mapTo[Vector[Product]]
} yield {
  ...
}
```

Comment: While we're on the topic, it's also better to use `pipeTo` to avoid closing over mutable state.  `(myActor ? MyActor.Search("...", 25)).mapTo[Vector[Product]].pipeTo(self)`